# Active Directory and External Email Accounts

Tags: email, account-security, active-directory, user-management, exchange

In my place of work we have an on-prem Active Directory with 'staff' accounts. Each of these AD accounts has an associated company email, e.g. john@example.com

Within the same AD we also have 'external' user accounts, e.g. suppliers, contractors etc. This allows the external users to login and access some of our systems using their AD credentials (user number and password). **None of these external users have an email address associated with their AD account.**

The only users with an AD email address are 'staff'. There are various reasons why we would like 'external' users to have an email address, e.g. Currently they cannot use the 'send to email' feature of our printers, as they have no associated email.

I have a few questions (I am not an AD administrator or security expert, and I'm not familiar with the email or AD infrastructure.)

1. is it technically possible to associate an external domain email address to our internal AD user accounts (e.g. john@gmail.com)
2. will doing this pose any security risks / why would AD admins be reluctant to do this
3. is there a better / safer alternative
4. does it make is any less secure if its AD on-prem or Azure

Comment: Welcome to the community. Could you please specify whether you're using Azure AD or locally deployed AD?

Comment: @SirMuffington Thanks, updated question!